# (Datatables/Ajax/Node): Am I really making a cross origin request? Is there a way I can make it from the same origin?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, datatables

So I'm building what I thought would be a simple table using the ajax feature from the jQuery DataTables library. The table is located at [URL]/forms/ and the data is at {URL}/forms/ajax. (Both work individually).
The problem is I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8080/forms/ajax?query=all&_=1468527565077. Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

From what I understand, a request from {URL}/forms for {URL}/forms/ajax should not be considered cross origin. This is the code I'm currently working off is below. Also, I have tried the following:

- Using/not using the node cors package (although I'm not willing to use the wildcard permissions). ]
- Pretty much every ajax object config style that the datatables api has
- Using jsonp as what express sends and as what ajax expects as a response
- changing the mime type manually to js
- Sending the response as a string and parsing it.

My Datatables config (which contains my ajax setup) is as follows:

```js
var table = $('#forms_table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        ajax: {
            "url":'/forms/ajax?query=all',
        }, 
        bSortable: true,
        deferRender: true,
        order: [[ 2, "asc" ], [3, "asc"], [4, "asc"]],
        asStripeClasses: [ 'even', 'odd', ],
        stripe: true,
    });
```

The /forms/ajax route ends with the following response:

```
function sendForms(forms, req, res){
    res.json({
        "data": fixed
});
```

If anyone can tell me what's going on (or just give me more ideas to try), I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you loading the page from which this code runs via a `file://` URL? If so, that's the problem. The cross-origin stuff comes into play when the URL of the page does not match the URL of the target. If you load the page from `http://localhost:8080/`, then things should get better.

Comment: Nope, not a file url. Its a localhost url (http if it matters), and I've tried it with the hostname and with just a forward slash.

Comment: @kaitlin — It should **not** say your origin is `null` if you are using `http://localhost` as the URL of the HTML document initiating the JavaScript.